# File get contents and string replace for multiple files

Tags: php, foreach, file-get-contents, str-replace, strpos

I have a number of files, alpha.php, beta.php and gamma.php in a folder named test. I need to get the contents of these three files and and replace a string in them with another string.
To replace everything in the folder, this worked:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./test') as $folder) {
    if ($folder->getExtension() === 'php') {
        $file = file_get_contents($folder->getPathname());
        if(strpos($file, "Hello You") !== false){
            echo "Already Replaced";
        }
        else {
            $str=str_replace("Go Away", "Hello You",$file);
            file_put_contents($folder->getPathname(), $str); 
            echo "done";
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to process all the files in the folder. I just want to get the 3 files: alpha.php, beta.php and gamma.php and process them.

Is there a way I can do this or I have to just get the files individually and process them individually? Thanks.

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: Not at all. The answers provided below by Lawrence Cherone and AbraCadaver worked.

Comment: Then you should accept one of them.  The check mark below the vote buttons.

Comment: Oh Ok. Both worked fine so I didn't know which one to accept over the other, I even tried accepting both but it seems we are allowed to accept only one, that's why I only upvoted them. No problems, Thanks for the guidance, I'll accept one right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `foreach` what you want:

```
foreach (['alpha.php', 'beta.php', 'gamma.php'] as $filename) {
    $file = file_get_contents("./test/$filename");

    if(strpos($file, "Hello You") !== false){
        echo "Already Replaced";
    }
    else {
        $str = str_replace("Go Away", "Hello You", $file);
        file_put_contents("./test/$filename", $str); 
        echo "done";
    }
}
```

You don't need the `if` unless you really need the `echo`s to see when there are replacements:

```
foreach (['alpha.php', 'beta.php', 'gamma.php'] as $filename) {
    $file = file_get_contents("./test/$filename");
    $str = str_replace("Go Away", "Hello You", $file);
    file_put_contents("./test/$filename", $str); 
}
```

Or you can get the count of replacements:

```
    $str = str_replace("Go Away", "Hello You", $file, $count);
    if($count) {        
        file_put_contents("./test/$filename", $str); 
    }
```

On Linux you could also try `exec` or something with [replace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/replace) or [repl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/replace) as they accept multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

If its predefined files then you dont need DirectoryIterator, simply replace the contents either with 3 lines, or a loop

```
<?php
$files = ['alpha.php', 'beta.php', 'gamma.php'];

foreach ($files as $file) 
    file_put_contents('./test/'.$file, str_replace("Go Away", "Hello You", file_get_contents('./test/'.$file)));
```